# how to extract exact information from unstructured text

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval

I want to extract some information from unstructured text.

For example, my text is "Control NewYork temperature under 39"

The information I want is ("control","NewYork", "temperature", "under", "39").

In the result information, "control" which represents the action, "NewYork" which represents the action target,"temperature" which is the indicator and "under 39" which represents the range.

However, the structure of text content is various.

Below are some typical cases.

```
"Control NewYork temperature under 39"
==>("control","NewYork", "temperature", "under", "39")

"give some money to my brother"
==>("give", "money", "my brother")

"Adjust the height of the table"
==>("adjust", "table", "height")
```

Is there any suggestion for  my problem ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You have several paradigms to do this kind of structured prediction.
The most common are:

Use Frame Semantics: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/SEMAFOR/

Use Semantic Role Labeling (SRL): http://cogcomp.org/page/demo_view/srl

The main difference is that SRL's Semantic Roles have different meanings for different verbs, while Frame Semantics is an abstraction that gives generic roles for a semantic concept.

You can easily find tools to do either Frame Semantic Parsing or SRL on Github. However, SRL is more widely used